# C Pthread Priority : Unable to get expected behavior

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

Here, I am trying to create two threads, assign priorities/policies to them and get the expected behavior.

Expected behavior: Thread which has highest priority(in this case, thread1) should execute always first. 
What I am seeing: Thread output gets mingled, meaning the priority is not being followed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>


void *thread_func1 ();
void *thread_func2 ();

int main (){

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_attr_t attr1, attr2; 

    struct sched_param param1, param2;

    int thread1_prio = 70;
    int thread2_prio = 69;

    int policy1, policy2;

    policy1 = SCHED_RR;
    policy2 = SCHED_RR;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr2);


    param1.sched_priority = thread1_prio;
    param2.sched_priority = thread2_prio;

    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr2, &param2);

    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, policy1);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr2, policy2);   

    pthread_attr_getschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
    pthread_attr_getschedparam(&attr2, &param2);

    pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(&attr1, &policy1);
    pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(&attr2, &policy2);  

    pthread_create(&thread1, &attr1, thread_func1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, &attr2, thread_func2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);


    return 0;
}

void *thread_func1 (void *var){

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Thread: 1\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void *thread_func2 (void *var){

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Thread: 2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- I also tried using `pthread_setschedprio`, still could not get results as expected.
- Executing the program as `root`

Prior posting this question, I did try to follow many posts / examples, but ended up getting more confused. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Was this not a genuine question? I mean Please correct me if it was stupid to post this and deserve downvotes as some of you already down-voted the post?

Comment: Each of your threads does I/O (through `printf`) and just about all kinds of I/O leads to the thread being put to sleep and preempted.

Comment: Generally, for synchronization between threads use the standard thread synchronizations primitives (semaphores, conditional variables, mutexes, etc.).

Comment: Is there any way I could test this feature? Without using any thread synchronization technique. i.e. Purely based on its assigned priorities?

Comment: Possibly by iterating more in the threads, and comparing the amount of lines written from each thread. Does thread 1 write more lines and get finished much quicker than thread 2?

Comment: I tried iterating them more (100..1000), the received output is pretty much look mingled again. Its hard to get convinced that thread1's priority is getting respected.

Comment: Then it's probably the I/O again. Perhaps try making `stdout` fully buffered or just print a space instead of a newline? Then each `printf` call should just write to an in-memory buffer and not to the terminal (unless you fill the buffer).

Comment: Removed new line, more or less same behavior. Sometimes even saw that Thread2 execution was started and completed before thread1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expected behavior: Thread which has highest priority (in this case, thread1) should execute first always.

In general, Linux doesn't work like that. The underlying design revolves around time sharing, where a task's priority influences the percentage of a CPU's time the task gets and has no effect on latency or preemption. It simply isn't intended to do "highest priority task that can run does run (and preempts lower priority tasks)" like you want.

In addition:

- pthread priorities are completely broken and unsupported for almost everything (except for the real-time scheduling policy that shouldn't be used by normal software, and probably shouldn't be used if you have hard real time requirements either).
- `nice()` is also broken, because it effects individual threads and not all threads belonging to the whole process like it's supposed to. This brokenness means that you can (sort of) use `nice()` instead of pthread priorities if you're brave.
- the behavior of the "priority"/nice limit is (or at least was, I haven't checked if its been fixed recently) also broken; in that regardless of what the limit is you can only reduce your task's priority and can't increase it back up to the limit. This completely breaks several common designs (e.g. "worker thread/s get a job from a queue then adjusts its priority to suit that job" and "thread pre-generates objects for future use and puts then in a pool, and adjusts its priority to meet demand (depending on how full/empty the pool is)").

The end result is that (without extreme hassles - e.g. a user-space threading layer on top of the kernel's broken mess) you're effectively left the ability to emulate a paltry "2 priority" system by abusing "SCHED_RR" (plus `nice()` for insignificant/minor adjustment) as the high/medium priority and "SCHED_IDLE" as the low priority.

Mostly; it's probably best to forget about writing software that uses thread priorities properly (it's too hard, not portable and only gives part of the benefits that it should). Of course that's also the underlying problem (because most software doesn't use thread priorities, so kernel developers don't really care enough to understand how a scheduler should work and don't fix thread priority, so most software doesn't use thread priorities - it's a self perpetuating feed-back loop of idiocy that's persisted for 3 decades now).

Comment: Thank you for the insight and explaining the things. I tried to read things, but on no platform it was clearly stated the facts which matters the most.

Answer (score 1):

I decorated your program to check for errors, and this line:

```
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
```

Consistently failed with EINVAL, root or not.  A quick check of the manual, showed that before this, you must:

```
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr1, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
```

That still doesn't quite fix it, a little more obscure is that you must set policy before priority, so the order is: setinheritsched, setschedpolicy, setschedparam.

Whether or not your particular posix-OS does anything useful with the scheduling parameters is anybodies guess, but at least this gives it a fighting chance.

A few notes:

1. To observe this properly, you will need to affine the threads to a single cpu.
2. You either need to make the priority of main() higher than either thread, or force the threads to start at a barrier, so you can release them simultaneously.  Otherwise your first thread could have run to completion before your second one has started.
3. Posix thread attributes are a mess, and you really want to test them for failures.  I typically wrap them in an assert-like macro.

With these corrections and enhancements, on my ubuntu 16, your program runs as expected.